# In browser JSX Transformation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to follow Mastering React book, There is a sample whose code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://<fb shortened url>/react-with-addons-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://<fb shortened url>/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://<fb shortened url>/JSXTransformer-0.13.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="view" />
    <script>
        var HelloReact = React.createClass({
            render: function () {
                return <h1 > Hello React < /h1>
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render( < HelloReact / > , document.body);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The above however does not seem to work. I am not getting a  HelloReact  in my document body.

Am totally new to React (and also JSX Transformation etc.,). 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The error I get in Chrome is

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing an element string, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.
```

Note : `fb shortened url` is `fb.me`, Stackoverflow was complaining about use of shorteners,

Comment: I can't believe the editor complains about the use of `fb.me` in a code block.

Answer (score 2):

> As many people have noticed already, React and React Native have both
>   switched their respective build systems to make use of Babel. This
>   replaced JSTransform, the source transformation tool that we wrote at
>   Facebook.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html

Use babel to convert the JSX syntax into JS and use the JS in your file

Comment: Further, [Babel in the browser is deprecated and already removed](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/) from the latest version of Babel, so you will really want to look into using a build process like Gulp or Webpack. Check out the [Babel setup page](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) to learn more.

Comment: Am I not using an older version of React : 0.14. Should it not work JSXTransformer in-browser ? I am a newbie so bear with me if the question is silly. I expected the examples in the book to work as is.